# R: Reorganize data frame with many paired species and abundance columns

Tags: r

I have been given a data frame of ecological data with several paired columns of species-abundance, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(site = 1:3,
                 sp1 = c("A","A","X"), abund1 = c(10,20,30),
                 sp2 = c("B","B","Y"), abund2 = c(10,20,30),
                 sp3 = c("C","Y","Z"), abund3 = c(10,20,30))

   site sp1 abund1 sp2 abund2 sp3 abund3
1     1   A     10   B     10   C     10
2     2   A     20   B     20   Y     20
3     3   X     30   Y     30   Z     30
```

(the actual data I am working with has 6 pairs of species and abundance columns)

I need to get it into a site vs. species format to do any further analysis, like so:

```
    site   A    B    C    X    Y    Z
1      1  10   10   10    0    0    0
2      2  20   20    0    0   20    0
3      3   0    0    0   30   30   30
```

The only thing I could think of was to first transform it into a 3-column data frame with columns "site", "species", and "abundance", and then use the reshape package. To do that, I was thinking of looping through each row of the original data frame with a for loop, transforming each row into a new data frame and then using rbind to group it all back together. But it seems very clunky and I am wondering if anyone can suggest a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try `recast` from `reshape2` to first melt the data frame then cast wide. Using `measure.var=c(2,4,6)` to identify the correct label columns. `recast` is able to combine the two functions by sending `id.var` and `measure.var` to `melt` then send all other arguments to `dcast`:

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df, id.var="site",measure.var=c(2,4,6), site~value,value.var="site",fill=0)
#   site A B C X Y Z
# 1    1 1 1 1 0 0 0
# 2    2 2 2 0 0 2 0
# 3    3 0 0 0 3 3 3
```

**update**

With new data:

```
s <- stack(df[-1])
newdf <- cbind(site=df[,1],as.data.frame(lapply(split(s, as.numeric(grepl("sp", s$ind))),'[',1)))
dcast(newdf, site~values.1, fill=0, value.var="values")
#   site  A  B  C  X  Y  Z
# 1    1 10 10 10  0  0  0
# 2    2 20 20  0  0 20  0
# 3    3  0  0  0 30 30 30
```

Or even:

```
x1 <- unlist(df[-1][c(T,F)], use.names=F)
x2 <- unlist(df[-1][c(F,T)], use.names=F)
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(site=df$site,x1,x2)
dcast(df2, site~x1, fill=0, value.var="x2")
```

This should work too:

```
m1 <- melt(df, id.var="site", measure.var=c(2,4,6))
m2 <- melt(df, id.var="site", measure.var=c(3,5,7))
m3 <- merge(m1, m2, by=1)[c(T,F)]
dcast(m3[!duplicated(m3[1:2]),], site~value.x, fill=0, value.var="value.y")
```

Comment: I tried it with my real data and it doesn't work. I lose the abundance values and only get the site numbers. It turns out my example data was poorly chosen - the abundance values were the same as the site numbers. I will edit it so you can see.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! I like your solution using unlist and then cbind. The last solution works too if you replace merge with cbind.

Answer (score 1):

Consider column binding multiple reshape2 `dcasts`, then selecting final columns:

```
library(reshape2)

reshapedf <- cbind(dcast(df[c('site', 'sp1', 'abund1')],
                         site~sp1, sum, value.var="abund1"),
                   dcast(df[c('site', 'sp2', 'abund2')],
                         site~sp2, sum, value.var="abund2"),
                   dcast(df[c('site', 'sp3', 'abund3')],
                         site~sp3, sum, value.var="abund3"))

reshapedf <- reshapedf[c('site','A','B','C','X','Y','Z')]

#   site    A   B   C   X   Y   Z
#1  1       10  10  10  0   0   0
#2  2       20  20  0   0   0   0
#3  3       0   0   0   30  30  30
```