# Panel Data formation in R

Tags: r, reshape2, panel-data

I have a data set with large number of companies. And for each company I estimated a measure for each month over a period of time i.e. year. But now I want to restructure this data set into a panel data. Below I illustrate the data set I have.

```
Month   Beta    A   B
Jan-05  Beta1   1   32
Jan-05  Beta2   2   32
Jan-05  Beta3   3   32
Jan-05  Beta4   4   32
Jan-05  Beta5   5   32
Jan-05  Beta6   6   32
Feb-05  Beta1   7   32
Feb-05  Beta2   8   32
Feb-05  Beta3   9   32
Feb-05  Beta4   10  32
Feb-05  Beta5   11  32
Feb-05  Beta6   12  32
Mar-05  Beta1   13  32
Mar-05  Beta2   14  32
Mar-05  Beta3   15  32
Mar-05  Beta4   16  32
Mar-05  Beta5   17  32
Mar-05  Beta6   18  32
Apr-05  Beta1   19  32
Apr-05  Beta2   20  32
Apr-05  Beta3   21  32
Apr-05  Beta4   22  32
Apr-05  Beta5   23  32
Apr-05  Beta6   24  32
May-05  Beta1   25  32
May-05  Beta2   26  32
May-05  Beta3   27  32
May-05  Beta4   28  32
May-05  Beta5   29  32
May-05  Beta6   30  32
Jun-05  Beta1   31  32
Jun-05  Beta2   32  32
Jun-05  Beta3   33  32
Jun-05  Beta4   34  32
Jun-05  Beta5   35  32
Jun-05  Beta6   36  32
Jul-05  Beta1   37  32
Jul-05  Beta2   38  32
Jul-05  Beta3   39  32
Jul-05  Beta4   40  32
Jul-05  Beta5   41  32
Jul-05  Beta6   42  32
Aug-05  Beta1   43  32
Aug-05  Beta2   44  32
Aug-05  Beta3   45  32
Aug-05  Beta4   46  32
Aug-05  Beta5   47  32
Aug-05  Beta6   48  32
Sep-05  Beta1   49  32
Sep-05  Beta2   50  32
Sep-05  Beta3   51  32
Sep-05  Beta4   52  32
Sep-05  Beta5   53  32
Sep-05  Beta6   54  32
Oct-05  Beta1   55  32
Oct-05  Beta2   56  32
Oct-05  Beta3   57  32
Oct-05  Beta4   58  32
Oct-05  Beta5   59  32
Oct-05  Beta6   60  32
Nov-05  Beta1   61  32
Nov-05  Beta2   62  32
Nov-05  Beta3   63  32
Nov-05  Beta4   64  32
Nov-05  Beta5   65  32
Nov-05  Beta6   66  32
Dec-05  Beta1   67  32
Dec-05  Beta2   68  32
Dec-05  Beta3   69  32
Dec-05  Beta4   70  32
Dec-05  Beta5   71  32
Dec-05  Beta6   72  32
```

As it can be observed six separate measures Beta1, Beta2, Beta3, Beta4, Beta5 and Beta6 have been calculated for each month. Now I want to reshape this into as follows

```
Month   Company Beta1   Beta2   Beta3   Beta4   Beta5   Beta6
Jan-05  A        1         2      3       4        5    6
Feb-05  A        7         8      9       10       11   12
Mar-05  A       13        14      15      16       17   18
Apr-05  A       19        20      21      22       23   24
May-05  A       25        26      27      28       29   30
Jun-05  A       31        32      33      34       35   36
Jul-05  A       37        38      39      40       41   42
Aug-05  A       43        44      45      46       47   48
Sep-05  A       49        50      51      52       53   54
Oct-05  A       56        57      58      59       60   61
Nov-05  A       62        63       64     65       66   67
Dec-05  A       68        69       70      71     72    73
Jan-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Feb-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Mar-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Apr-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
May-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Jun-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Jul-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Aug-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Sep-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Oct-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Nov-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
Dec-05  B       32        32       32      32     32    32
```

My original data set has over thousand columns. I have referred to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007913/create-a-panel-data-frame) but my data set is different from this one. I would really appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: In the first dataset, what identifies the company?

Comment: The column header A and B are the company names.

Comment: This is similar but not exact http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324746/r-reorganize-data-frame-with-many-paired-species-and-abundance-columns/35325633#35325633

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic `recast`. The `id.var` argument goes to `melt`, the other arguments go to `dcast`.

The first function `melt` produces a long data frame specified with `id.var=c("Month", "Beta")`. Therefore the output will combine columns "A" and "B" in a column called `variable` and create a separate `value` column. With that melted `data.frame` We can then cast wide with `dcast`. The formula `Month+variable ~ Beta` has id variables on the Left of the tilde(`~`) and measure variables on the right. Both functions are combined in `recast` for convenience.

If the order matters, convert the Month column to dates and order at the end:

```
library(zoo)
library(reshape2)
df[,1] <- as.yearmon(df[,1], "%b-%y")
newdf <- recast(df, id.var=c("Month", "Beta"), Month+variable~Beta, value.var="value")
newdf <- newdf[order(newdf$variable,newdf$Month),]
newdf[,1] <- format(newdf$Month, "%b-%y")
newdf
#     Month variable Beta1 Beta2 Beta3 Beta4 Beta5 Beta6
# 1  Jan-05        A     1     2     3     4     5     6
# 3  Feb-05        A     7     8     9    10    11    12
# 5  Mar-05        A    13    14    15    16    17    18
# 7  Apr-05        A    19    20    21    22    23    24
# 9  May-05        A    25    26    27    28    29    30
# 11 Jun-05        A    31    32    33    34    35    36
# 13 Jul-05        A    37    38    39    40    41    42
# 15 Aug-05        A    43    44    45    46    47    48
# 17 Sep-05        A    49    50    51    52    53    54
# 19 Oct-05        A    55    56    57    58    59    60
# 21 Nov-05        A    61    62    63    64    65    66
# 23 Dec-05        A    67    68    69    70    71    72
# 2  Jan-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 4  Feb-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 6  Mar-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 8  Apr-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 10 May-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 12 Jun-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 14 Jul-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 16 Aug-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 18 Sep-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 20 Oct-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 22 Nov-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
# 24 Dec-05        B    32    32    32    32    32    32
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to rearrange it such that company A values for each measure from Jan-05 to Dec-05 come first than comes same for company B.Its really close to my desired output.

Comment: That is just a sort at the end. The hard work is in the example.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to sort it, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: If you add `dput(head(mydata))` where mydata is the name of your data.frame I can see the structure of your variables

Comment: I added the sort to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update but although same same series has been created that is A first than B but I don't why the months are alphabetically arranged like Apr Aug and so on.

Comment: As I asked, the inner structure of your dates do matter. If you have character or factors you will have to convert them to a date format.

Comment: I see, this is the problem whenever I write a dataframe to csv and then import it back to r, the data format is always changed to factor.

Comment: I added a conversion for you. It will work for both `factor` and `character`

Comment: I receive error `Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x),  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument`

Comment: I wish you could understand how important it is to add a piece of your actual data. I will ask again, pretty please, with cherries on top, help me help you. Add `dput(head(mydf))` to your question. I do not have your data in front of me. All I have is your example and explanation.

Comment: If your data is too big then add `dput(mydata[1:10, 1:5])` to get a smaller set.

Comment: I have added the original data set some part. I thank you for your patience.

Comment: Your example does not have any "A" or "B" columns so I cannot use it for paneling. But based on the structure the solution above should work. Can you please be more specific about the error you are receiving and where you are receiving it?

Comment: The code works perfect for my original dataset, only problem occurs is the  alphabetical arrangement of months. The error I stated above occurred when the code you provided to change factor to date.

Comment: Are you referring to the line `format(newdf$Month, "%b-%y")`?

Comment: that is not an alphabetical arrangement. I changed the look from `Jan 2005` to `Jan-2005`. It's just a way to add the dash. The arrangement happens in the previous line `newdf[order(newdf$variable,newdf$Month),]`

Comment: I have added the output that I receive after running the code `newdf <- recast(df, id.var=c("Month", "Beta"), Month+variable~Beta, value.var="value")`

Comment: That can't be the code after that line. That line would produce output with Month and 'variable' with the Betas going wide. Do you mean it is the original code?

Comment: Thank you I got the desired output. Thanks for you patience I hope I don't kicked out from this website so will be more adequate in explaining my questions in future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104472/discussion-between-pierre-lafortune-and-faith).

Answer (score 1):

Using functions from package {tidyr}:

```
df <- data.frame(Month = c(rep("Jan-05", 6), rep("Feb-05",6)),  
                 Beta = c(paste0("Beta",1:6), paste0("Beta",1:6)), 
                 A  = 1:12,  
                 B=rep(32,12))

df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, key = Company, value = val, A, B)

df3 <- tidyr::spread(data = df2, key = Beta, value = val)

##   Month Company Beta1 Beta2 Beta3 Beta4 Beta5 Beta6
##1 Feb-05       A     7     8     9    10    11    12
##2 Feb-05       B    32    32    32    32    32    32
##3 Jan-05       A     1     2     3     4     5     6
##4 Jan-05       B    32    32    32    32    32    32
```

Comment: @Faith what exactly is "inconvenient" about a two-line solution that uses a commonly available package? What exactly is inefficient about this approach? My testing shows comparable computation times to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the same answer in the Reshape pdf which is available online. 
Please go through this link.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape/reshape.pdf

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/reshape2.pdf

```
# This is an example. 
names(airquality) <- tolower(names(airquality))
aqm <- melt(airquality, id=c("month", "day"), na.rm=TRUE)
cast(aqm, day ~ month ~ variable)
# Not only sorting there are many other possiblities. 
cast(aqm, month ~ variable, mean)
cast(aqm, month ~ . | variable, mean)
cast(aqm, month ~ variable, mean, margins=c("grand_row", "grand_col"))
cast(aqm, day ~ month, mean, subset=variable=="ozone")
cast(aqm, month ~ variable, range)
cast(aqm, month ~ variable + result_variable, range)
cast(aqm, variable ~ month ~ result_variable,range)
```

If you follow all the examples, there is your answer. Reshape is handy package. 
May this helps you.